# CComVariant passing as VARIANT

Tags: c++, com, variant

I want to call a 3rd party function from my code. The function's prototype is:

```
HRESULT foo(/*[in]*/VARIANT, /*[in]*/VARIANT*, /*[out]*/VARIANT*)
```

Currently I am using CComVariant wrappers around my VARIANT variables, and I want to pass them to this function. I am a little bit confused, how should I do it. In the case of the input arguments, should I just pass them directly, or detach them into a simple VARIANT and pass those variables? As I can see, both version works, but which one is the cleaner and recommended method? My current code is something like this:

```
CComVariant param0(CComBSTR( "Hello world"));
CComVariant param1(VARIANT_FALSE);
CComVariant param2;
HRESULT hr = foo(param0, &param1, &param2);
```

Comment: `/*[in]*/ VARIANT*` -- really?

Comment: Yes, it's not a typo. :) I don't understand it either, but that's another story.

Comment: The code is okay (no specific value detachment before or after call is necessary; the snippet does it all). Why? That's another story, but it's fine.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it correctly: When I pass the argument by value, the object is sliced, so only the VARIANT part is copied, and as long as the function only reads it, won't cause any problem. After the function returns, the resources will be freed at the end of the block, right?
In the case of out argument: the argument passed through base pointer, the function writes to the VARIANT part (it's already initialized by the CComVariant's constructor), after the function returns, the resources are freed by the destructor when the variable goes out of scope.

Comment: About right. when [in] argument is, as you say, sliced and then execution returns from the call - there is nothing to free, the original of the "sliced" copy is owned by someone and he will release the resources in a normal way unrelated to this slicing. With [out] argument you provide a placeholder to get filled. You are responsible to free data. In this sample, you provide placeholder as `CComVariant` instance which automatically frees whatever is written to it when the variable goes out of scope. That is, it's you who releases resources and you do it with the help of this helper class.

Comment: Nothing is sliced, CComVariant does not add any additional fields nor virtual methods to the VARIANT struct.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code is okay and can hardly be done better given how `ATL::CComVariant` is designed unless you spend some time writing helper functions. A couple of thoughts on that.

Passing `CComVariant` as `in VARIANT` is okay - the base part is just member-wise copied into the function parameter and used by the called function from there. No deep copying happens and that's okay, the callee can use the copy just as well, if it wants to deep copy the parameter or `AddRef()` it - it still can do so.

Passing address of `CComVariant` as `in VARIANT` is okay (`CComVariant*` is implicitly upcast to `VARIANT*`, the function accesses the subobject), but not the best code in the world. Here's why. There's a lot of similar classes which own resources, the most important of them are `ATL::CComBSTR`, `_bstr_t`, `ATL::CComPtr`, `_com_ptr_t` and all of them have `operator&()` overloaded and also those of them which belong to `ATL` namespace just return the pointer to the stored pointer but `_bstr_t` and `_com_ptr_t` release the owned object before returning the pointer. Which is why this:

```
ATL::CComPtr<IUnknown> ptr( initialize() );
&ptr;
```

and this:

```
_com_ptr_t<IUnknown> ptr( initialize() );
&ptr;
```

have different effects. Neither `ATL::CComVariant` nor `_variant_t` have `operator&()` overloaded which complicates things a bit further. The cleaner way would be to use an "accessor extractor" method such as `_variant_t::GetVARIANT()` but `ATL::CComVariant` has not such method. So using `&` is the only option you have here.

Passing `CComVariant` address obtained using `&` as `out VARIANT*` is okay, but again not the best code in the world. It's fine when you know for sure the variant is empty but this code:

```
CComVariant var( obtainIUnknown() );
foo( whatever, whatever, &var );
```

will blindly overwrite the pointer and cause the previously referenced object to be leaked. A better way would be to use something like `_variant_t::GetAddress()` which clears the variant and then returns a pointer to raw `VARIANT` but again `ATL::CComVariant` has no such method.

So the bottom like is you code is okay, just be careful when modifying it. If you happen to write a lot of code like this you may be better off writing helper functions which do those "extraction" manipulations.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I have never used COM before, so it was really helpful!

Comment: @sharptooth would you mind helping me with this question I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42295574/how-to-convert-8209-array-object-variant-to-vt-variant